# Filter Pandas DataFrame based on style

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-styles

This [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html#Building-styles) shows how to apply styles `pandas.DataFrame`. How can we select the yellow cells from `df`?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], "B": [1, 7, 14, 5, 3]})

def apply_color(v):
    if v % 2 == 0:
        return "background-color: yellow"
    else:
        return ""
df.style.applymap(apply_color)
```

[image]

Comment: are you looking for `df[df.mod(2).eq(0)]`?

Comment: What would you like the filter to give you back? Series of integers in this case or just positions of the matched ones?

Comment: @anky no, that is a filter based on values. I would like to select cells based on colors. Let's say you received a pickle file of `df` and you have no idea how the style was applied. How can we select only the yellow cells?

Comment: Are the styles preserved/recorded in a `.pkl`? I feel like you will need access to the styling function, not just the data

Comment: @ALollz yeah exactly, that is what I am trying to find out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure this fully solves the problem, but here is a partial solution

`df.style.applymap` returns a `Styler` object: [Source](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.2.1/pandas/io/formats/style.py#L62-L1657).

After displaying the dataframe the style changes are stored in the ctx attribute of the Styler:

So, by assigning the style.applymap to a variable, you can get the Styler

```
a = df.style.applymap(apply_color)

#then executing:

a

#gives you the dataframe, styled with yellow background

#now, you can access the style by doing


a.ctx

#this returns


defaultdict(list,
        {(0, 0): [''],
         (0, 1): [''],
         (1, 0): ['background-color: yellow'],
         (1, 1): [''],
         (2, 0): [''],
         (2, 1): ['background-color: yellow'],
         (3, 0): ['background-color: yellow'],
         (3, 1): [''],
         (4, 0): [''],
         (4, 1): ['']})
```

Contributions by [E.K.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3128336/e-k):

find cell ids as follows:

```
for cell, color in a.ctx.items():
    if 'background-color: yellow' in color:
        print(cell, color, df.iloc[cell])
```

Comment: Oh this is perfect! We can just loop through `for cell, color in a.ctx.items():` and select values `df.iloc[cell]` where the color is yellow

Comment: Yeah, the reason why this is not complete, is that sometimes the contents of the ctx attribute seem to disappear

Comment: Interesting, I have not experienced `a.ctx` loosing its values so far. Any examples you can share?

Comment: Ah, no this was my mistake. I tried q=df.style.applymap(apply_color) and then immediately q.ctx, which gave the empty dict. But that means that the function is never executed, so the attribute is empty.

Comment: Yup I have seen that. I think your solution works!

Comment: @E.K.  have updated the answer. feel free to edit.